# Finding a point on a curve where the tangent is parallel to another line noted

Tags: calculus

Find the point on the curve $y=x^2+2$ where the tangent is parallel to the line $2x+y-1=0$

I understand the answer is $(-1,3)$ but I can't find a way to get there... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $2x+y-1=0$ has a slope of $-2$

the derivative of $x^2+2$ is $2x$

for the $x$-coordinate solve $2x=-2$

for the $y$-coordinate plug the value of $x$ into $y=x^2+2$

Comment: * solve for $2x=-2$

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to find the derivative of a function?  The derivative of the curve function will tell you the slope at any point $x$.

So, figure out the slope of $2x+y=1$ and then find the $x$ value of the curve's derivative that returns that same slope.

That will be the $x$ value for your point.  You will have to plug that into your curve function to get the $y$ value.

Answer (score 0):

pick a point $(a, a^2 + 2)$ on the graph of $y = x^2 + 2.$ the tangent at this point has slope $2a$ so the tangent has the equation $y = a^2 + 2 + 2a(x-a) = 2ax + 2 - a^2$ if this line is to match the line $2x + y - 1 = 0$ then $a = -1$ and the point at which this line is tangent is $(-1, 3).$